# Difficulty in updating row of records in access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I usually get this error often,i need to overcome it once and for all with you guys help
Am getting "Syntax error in Update Statement" whenever i click on my update button...Subsequently,have tried different code approach to solving this Error but its all lead to avail
Here is my code:

```
try
    {

       // UPDATE Categories SET CategoryName = @categoryname, Description = @categorydescription WHERE (CategoryID = @categoryid)
        string query = "UPDATE Cashier SET  Surname = @Surname, Firstname = @Firstname, Othername = @Othername, Username = @Username, Password = @Password, Phonenumber = @Phonenumber, Email = @Email WHERE (ID = @ID)";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connect);

       if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save?...", "Confirmation Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Surname;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Firstname;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Othername",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Othername;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Username;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Password;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Phonenumber;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Email;
            //OleDbDataReader dr;
            //dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            connect.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully Updated!!!");
            connect.Close();

            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox5.Clear();
            textBox6.Clear();
            textBox7.Clear();
            textBox8.Clear();
        }


       else
        {
            this.Show();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Password is a reserved word, escape it: `[Password]`, but you really ought never save passwords as plain text: salt and hash them.  You should also get into the habit of using `Add` rather than `AddWithValue`...and your app is leaking.

Comment: owk...now am getting "Datatype mis match in citeria expression" Error...any help?

Comment: Probably the problem is with your @ID parameter. In your provided code you've got it commented out,but i guess it must be an int instead of a varchar...

Comment: yeah...i commented it out because its an auto increment field which the user should not have the access to alter whatever number or value his or her record fall into...

Comment: You are not using AddWithValue correctly - dont ignore the pop up help that the IDE offers in Intellisense.  Use `Add` instead, and be sure to also add the ID parameter value, but add it **last**.

Comment: also does Access DB support `@` Parameter or should you be using `?` for Parameters.. why not do a simple google search on `C# UPDATE Statement in MS ACCESS` there are plenty of examples. also with reserved words wrap the column names around `[Password]` for example. Second suggestion instead of writing the TextBox.Clear for all the individual TextBox controls, try looking up how to use `foreach(Control ctrl in Controls)` then you can use one method to clear the many TextBoxes also there is a simple 1 liner Linq you could use as well

Comment: Yea...i tend to do the textbox.clear code later,i just grouped all the code together so as to make u know what exactly am talking about...Access of course supports @ Parameter,i used the same approach for inserting records and it worked quite well

Comment: you commented ID parameter out,but you are using it in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

[`AddWithValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is declared like this:

```
public OleDbParameter AddWithValue(
    string parameterName,
    object value
)
```

I.e.: the second parameter must be the value, not a type.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", Surname);
```

or use `Add`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Surname;
```

Comment: i really appreciate your wanting to help me out...i did as u'v instructed and am still get "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." Error...All of my Column are in "long text" datatype except the Phonenumber column which i tagged to be "Number" and ID in "Auto Number"...

Comment: Not only the type parameter `OleDbType` must match, but also the value passed to the parameter. I.e., if the phone number is given as string (from a TextBox), then first convert it to an `int` or whatever matches best the type of the column. In Access, Number columns have a sub-type: Long, double, decimal etc.

Comment: If `Phonenumber` is some Number column, then `OleDbType.VarChar` is certainly wrong.